# Nodejs: websocket routing based on URL without port proxying

Tags: node.js, url, websocket, appfog, paas

I am trying to do a game in html5 with serverside logic in node.js and that uses raw websockets (not Socket.IO, I need binary data). I wish to have multiple "rooms", thus multiple websocket servers, all having separate URLs. Currently, I only found a way to have each websocket server attached to a specific port, and then proxy the upgrade requests(not entirely sure how it works) to the right port based on the url.

It works on my computer. The problem is that when I try to submit it to a PaaS provider (AppFog), the code fails because they don't permit opening any ports other than the provided http port.

Here is a pretty cleared up version of my code:

```
//start web server (basic static express server) on 8080
//    ...


//start game server and listen to port 9000
//   I use the ws module for websockets
// I plan to have a couple of these "game servers"
//    ...


//open the proxy server.

var httpProxy= require('http-proxy');

var webProxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy){

   // I need http requests to be redirected to the "game servers"

   if(req.url.substring(0, "/room1".length) === "/room1") // if starts with "/room1"

      proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
         host: 'localhost',
         port: 9000
      });


   else

      proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
         host: 'localhost',
         port: 8080
      });

}

webProxyServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {

   //redirecting logic goes here

   if(req.url=="/room1/"){

      webProxyServer.proxy.proxyWebSocketRequest(req, socket, head, {
         host: 'localhost',
         port: 9000
      })
   }

});


webProxyServer.listen(8000);  //the "outside port".
```

My question: is it somehow possible to open websocket servers without listening to any specific ports, and to manually attach sockets to them so I don't need to open any ports other than the basic http port? I know Socket.IO somehow does it. Maybe there is a way to listen to the upgrade event of a http server and pass the socket to the right websocket server?

I am pretty new to server-side stuff, so extra info here and there would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Appfog does not support websockets.

[Feature Roadmap page](https://docs.appfog.com/roadmap#features) - bottom of page:    shows websockets as something coming soon (i.e. they don't support it).